# material UI Multiple Select not viewing several selected items when they selected, my be css issue

Tags: reactjs, material-design, materialize, material-ui

I tried to use the [Multiple Select](https://codesandbox.io/s/92x5rp95r). But I get a difference, is that when many items are selected, they are not viewed, I couldn't change the height to be enough to display selected options. please help.

I am sure it is `height` property because I added `height:auto` using chrome console and so selected options could be viewed and issue solved at the console.  You can guide me through adding the height feature properly. The `height` may be added to `chips` style at the styles.

By the way, the problem doesn't appear on a fresh copy of create-react-app that I tested it on it today, but my project which faces the problem is based on a create-project-app generated long time ago, I thought updates or create-react-app releases make difference.

Material UI version: v1.0.0-beta.33

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "auth/google": {
      "target": "https://server243.azurewebsites.net"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "https://server243.azurewebsites.net"
    },
    "/apis/*": {
      "target": "https://server243.azurewebsites.net"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "aws-amplify": "^0.2.0",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^0.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "react-loader": "^2.4.2",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^0.3.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.6.8",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "react-select-me": "^0.9.0",
    "react-virtualized-select": "^3.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-auth": "0.0.5-beta5",
    "redux-auth-wrapper": "^2.0.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.1.2",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.3",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Temporary solution: I updated the `height` and `padding` at node_modules\material-ui\Select\Select.js but I wish I get right way to solve it.

```
    selectMenu: {
  width: 'auto', // Fix Safari textOverflow
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
  whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  lineHeight: 'calc(1em + ' + (theme.spacing.unit * 2 - 2) + 'px)',

//  I, abdulrhman, added the following:
 height:'auto',
 paddingTop: 20,

},
```

Comment: When I run the codesandbox example you linked to, the chips box expands to display all of the selected chips. Are you talking about making the Name and Tag boxes expand in the same way?

Comment: no, don't need Name and Tag boxes to expand. By the way, I said I ran select successfully on a create-react-app project, so no need to judge on sandbox. understand the problem, please. if something not clear please let me know. thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the specific version numbers or `package.json` file of the project that doesn't work would be helpful. Otherwise it's kind of hard to debug behavior that can't be reproduced.

Comment: updated post! thank you

Comment: I still can't reproduce your problem on Firefox with the package versions you specified. Perhaps you should just update to the latest versions if that fixes your problem and doesn't create too much extra work. Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: thank you, what do you mean extra work?

Comment: There have been some  API changes in material-ui since beta 24. You'll need to update your code to be compatible with those changes.

Comment: at my package json is     "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.24", and existing version is v1.0.0-beta.33. So, shall I run (npm install --save material-ui@next) now to update? or how to update? I appreciate your notes.

Comment: `npm install --save material-ui@1.0.0-beta.33` should work.

Comment: found that the update solved the problem, thank you. Could you please post an answer about that? I want to mark this question as answered.

Comment: I posted the update as an answer. Glad I could help and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `SelectField` will have the expected behavior in newer versions of the beta. You should try updating to the latest version (`material-ui^1.0.0-beta.33` at the time of this writing).

You can update to this version with the `npm` command:

```
npm install --save material-ui@1.0.0-beta.33
```